# How to create framework file from existing sdk codes by xcode

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode, sdk

I am completely new to ios , mac and xcode.
Basically I am a xamarin developer which is based on .net,at the moment
our client have a requirement to use an existing sdk in their xamarin ios project.
To create a native binding for xamarin ios,we need to create a .framework file.

So how to create a .framework file from existing SDK Codes,for example lets say this one

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk

This is just an example...I know libraries for Facebook already exists in .Net

Comment: You just download the repo and build it. What exactly are struggling with?

Comment: ya i tried ,but it is giving error...like provisional certificate missing...but why provisional certificate is needed,if sdk is open library

Comment: Any binary Xcode emits needs to be signed somehow. Provisioning profile contains information on which behalf to sign this binary, and also it checks whether the developer is eligible to do so (e.g. if the project requires Push Notification capabilities, you can only build it with paid Apple Developer Program).

Comment: ok, unfortunately it is indeed a push notification library that client is looking for..So it is not possible to create a framework file without provisional certifcate from a open source sdk,for android i was able to create aar files for the same sdk...for ios i am really struggling

Comment: so your framework can contain functionality that creates or processes push notifications, BUT the final configuration of the push notifications is done on each app which integrates with the framework.

Comment: @akjndklskver yes exactly...that sdk just contains all functionalities..pushes will be configured through device specific

Comment: I think you are coming from the wrong angle: it's not your responsibility to release Facebook SDK (and probably you cannot do it legally either). Based on facebook instructions you have to use package manager to include it, and that needs to be done on app itself.

Comment: @akjndklskver nope.. i can use facebook sdk for creating aars in case of android..and convert that aar to a .net compatibilty dll...what i am trying to say is...any open source library/SDK(please note i am using word library) can be converted to a specific form in specific platform....in android if we build ...the output is aar...for ios if we build it should generate some package or framework ..for example cant we create framework from this https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk

Comment: if facebook license allows that - sure you can: either framework or xcframework (preferable). But you still have to sign it. Alternative is you could also just include source code for 3rd-party SDK in your app, and compile it together with everything else (but that's ugly)